# Почему stoi выдает ошибку invalid_argument?

Tags: c++

```
string side;
int rows;
while (true)
{
    getline(cin, side);
    if (sideIsValid(side)) break;
}
rows = stoi(side);
```

Вот фрагмент кода одной из функций. При первом вызове все проходит на ура. Но при втором `stoi` дает `invalid_argument`, причём через `getline` ещё не было передано новое значение для `side`. `sideIsValid()` выглядит так:

```
bool sideIsValid(string side)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < side.length(); i++)
    {
        if ((side[i] >= 48 && side[i] <= 57) || side[i] == '.' || side[0] == '-')
        {
        continue;
        }
        else return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Написана какая-то белиберда. Какой может быть "второй `stoi`" если "через getline ещё не было передано новое значение для side"?? Как же тогда управление попало в `stoi` второй раз?

Comment: Если смотреть через отладчик, side ничего не содержит. Это конечно звучит как шутка, но возникает ошибка до повторного ввода

Comment: Ничего не понятно. "Если смотреть через отладчик" в каком месте? Если вы находитесь "до повторного ввода", то каким образом вы попали в `stoi`, которая вызывается *после* ввода? В общем, приводите ясный и понятный полный код. Пока что наблюдается какая-то словесная каша.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша функция неправильно проверяет корректность строки. Например, если вы вводили что-нибудь до этого, то в `cin` остался символ `'\n'`, `getline` читает до этого символа и получается пустая строка, что ваша функция считает валидным значение, но для `stoi` оно таким не является. Примеры ошибочных строк, которые ваша функция посчитает корректным: `""`, `"."`, `".5"`, `"-."`, `"-.5"`.

Цикл до ввода корректного числа можно сделать так:

```
int rows;
while (true) {
    cin >> rows;
    if (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear(); // unset failbit
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        //cout << "Error" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо